# Can't make FancyBox works proprely when it's inside a container initially not renderd

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, fancybox

I been trying to solve this for several hours today. I have reach (in some way) a solution but is not working as expected.

I'm new into the jQuery's world so i'll try to be clear.
In my example i have a xhtml page that include another xhtml page inside with the 
`<ui:include>` tag. The page that is included i'ts not originally rendered (due to all the pictures that contains). When it's rendered via a `<p:commandLink>` the page is shown with all the pictures correctly. Every picture is a `<h:ouputLink>` that shows a fancyBox, but with a behaviour a little bugged.

When the included page is finally rendered and i click for the first time the `<h:ouputLink>` the fancyBox doesn't show, but subsequent clicks opens the fancyBox and it works properly. I can't figure why.
Im using jsf2, PrimeFaces 3.02, FancyBox 1.7.
My code:

The main.xhtml

```
    <--Main xhtml-->
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:panelGrid id="panelGridMain"
        rendered="#{myBean.actualPage eq 'main'}">
        <p:commandLink
            id="showIncludedPage"
            actionListener="#{myBean.setPage('test')}"
            update="@form">
            <h:graphicImage value="/Image/TbnPic1.jpg"/>
        </p:commandLink>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGroup id="myTestPanel"  rendered="#{myBean.actualPage eq 'test'}">
        <ui:include src="test.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Test.xhtml

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:outputLink value="/Images/Pic1.jpg" id="example1" title=""  >
            <h:graphicImage alt="example1" value="/Images/TbnPic1.jpg" />
    </h:outputLink>
</ui:component>
```

Finally my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {        
        $("#myForm\\:example1").live("click",function(e) {
            alert(e.isDefaultPrevented());
            if (! e.isDefaultPrevented()){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            $(this).fancybox();
          });
});
```

Some aclarations:

*I red that `.on()` is recommend but it didn't work for me, i need to do more tests.

*I had to add the e.preventDefault() to my .js because when i clicked the link to pop-up the fancyBox , the link was redirecting to the url containing the photo (eg: localhost:8080/../Images/Pic1.jpg)

*if the page was originally rendered the fancyBox worked properly.

Thanks for any help, i hope you can understand the problem =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the job in the `oncomplete` of the `<p:commandLink>` instead.

```html
<p:commandLink
    id="showIncludedPage"
    actionListener="#{myBean.setPage('test')}"
    update="@form"
    oncomplete="$('#myForm\\:example1').fancybox()">
    <h:graphicImage value="/Image/TbnPic1.jpg"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

---

As to your questions:

> *When the included page is finally rendered and i click for the first time the  the fancyBox doesn't show, but subsequent clicks opens the fancyBox and it works properly. I can't figure why.*

The Fancybox has to be applied *before* the user clicks the link.

---

> *I red that .on() is recommend but it didn't work for me, i need to do more tests.*

This is new in jQuery 1.7. As far as I know, PF 3.0.x ships with jQuery 1.6. The [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is then recommended over `.live()`. However, you can't use them to directly manipuate elements when they are newly added. You can only use them on future events like `click`, `hover`, etc.

---

> *I had to add the e.preventDefault() to my .js because when i clicked the link to pop-up the fancyBox , the link was redirecting to the url containing the photo (eg: localhost:8080/../Images/Pic1.jpg)*

This is normal. JavaScript doesn't take over the element's default behaviour. It just adds behaviour. If you want to block the default behaviour, you'd indeed need to call `e.preventDefault()`, or in case of a `live()` better, to `return false;`. Read the [`jQuery.live()` API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) carefully.

Comment: Claps, i need more practice in order to figure things like this. Thanks again for this, and all the tips.

Answer (score 1):

In the jQuery code that you have written, what you are doing in the click event is:

```
$(this).fancybox();
```

This way, you are applying the fancybox when the link is clicked for the first time. That's why when you click the link second time, the fancybox opens perfectly.
You can fix this behavior by applying the fancybox on page load, so you'll have to change the jQuery code to this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {        
        $("#example1").fancybox();
    }
);
```

What this will do is apply the fancybox directly to the link with id 'example1' on page load and the fancybox will open on first click.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need to initialize fancybox in `$(document).ready` first. If you don't then on the first click event fancybox initialize itself and subsequent clicks it works as it supposed to. After initialization if you bind the fancybox with any event it should work on single click. I had similar kind of problem and works perfectly for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $("#myForm\\:example1").fancybox();

    $("#myForm\\:example1").live("click",function(e) {
          alert(e.isDefaultPrevented());
          if (! e.isDefaultPrevented()){
                e.preventDefault();
          }
          $(this).fancybox();
    });
});
```